# How to pick a commit in sub-branch and merge it into main branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch, commit, git-cherry-pick

So I have:

```
master
+commit1
+commit2
+commit3

myBranch
+commitA
+commitB
+commitC
```

I want to pick commitB in myBranch and merge it to master branch, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick commitB
```

Or even better, `git help cherry-pick` and read it.